# Ninject.MVC5 Release Scope Never Called - OutOfMemoryException

Tags: ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I'm new to Ninject, but I've become convinced that the out of the box configuration for Ninject.MVC5 NuGet package never actually releases the objects scoped to the HttpContext.  I consistently get an OutOfMemoryException after a bout of repeated heavy memory usage by some of my larger reports.

So to prove I wasn't losing my mind I created an empty test project.  I created a default project in VS 2017 by File -> New Project -> C# -> Web -> ASP.NET Web Application -> MVC (in the modal).  This is a new solution too, to be clear.  I then installed Ninject 3.2.2 (not the latest; <3.3 is required for Ninject.MVC5), then installed Ninject.MVC5.

Then I went to HomeController.cs and first added a class to the bottom of the file:

```
public class MemoryEater : IDisposable
{
    public List<int> _nums = new List<int>();

    public MemoryEater()
    {
        var rand = new Random(); // Use random so that I get a bit of CPU usage I can see in Task Manager
        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < 2_500_000; ++cnt)
        {
            var key = rand.Next();
            _nums.Add(key);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_nums != null)
            _nums = null;
    }
}
```

Then I added a constructor to HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    readonly MemoryEater _me;

    public HomeController(MemoryEater me)
    {
        _me = me;
    }
```

And finally I opened up NinjectWebCommon.cs, which I didn't modify in any way up until now (this file created 100% by installing Ninject.MVC5 via NuGet), and added one line to RegisterServices:

```
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<MemoryEater>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
    }
```

I then run the app with IISExpress and viewed in Chrome (on Windows 10).  I refresh the page and watch the memory usage climb; some GCs happen clearly as the memory usage drops, which is expected b/c the List object has to grow.  But it keeps climbing past 600MB and, after a few dozen refreshes, I get an OutOfMemoryException in my app.

So I went a step further and copied the source from GitHub for OnePerRequestHttpModule.cs into a new file in my project, and split up the method DeactivateInstancesForCurrentHttpRequest so that I could put a breakpoint where ICache.Clear is called:

```
    public void DeactivateInstancesForCurrentHttpRequest()
    {
        if (this.ReleaseScopeAtRequestEnd)
        {
            var context = HttpContext.Current;
            this.MapKernels(kernel => ClearCacheOfContext(kernel, context)); // BREAKPOINT A
        }
    }

    private void ClearCacheOfContext(IKernel kernel, HttpContext context)
    {
        kernel.Components.Get<ICache>().Clear(context); // BREAKPOINT B
    }
```

I changed NinjectWebCommon to use my new copy of OnePerRequestHttpModule and put breakpoints at A and B.  After every request A is called but B is **never called**.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a legit bug?  It seems unthinkable to me that this bug could exist and me, a n00b to Ninject, could be the first one to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a closer look at the version of your Ninject.Web.Common nuget package.

If it is less than 3.2.2, this is the cause of your issue.

[This bug has been fixed in version 3.2.2](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/issues/15)

Comment: Wow, that was fixed in 2014.  When I installed Ninject.MVC5 I installed the latest non-beta release.  I guess NuGet automatically pulled the versions of Ninject.Web.Common and Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost that existed before Ninjuct.MVC5 3.2.1 existed.  That's just an educated guess, but that's the only way I can explain having installed this a week ago and getting versions from 2014.  Thx!